# Better way to validation iPhone form

Tags: iphone, objective-c, validation

What is the efficient way to validate a form in iPhone? Basic validation like if the all required textFields are filled and some validation for email and phone.

- Is there way to show all the error once the submit button clicked? (I'm basically highlighting the textField red)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually show the validation *before* the submit button has been tapped, by using the `UITextField` delegate methods.

So to achieve this you would just use the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method ([documented here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)) to detect when the user had moved from one text field to another, and then you could immediately highlight a field red if it didn't pass your validation test.

This is a nice approach, because the user immediately knows their input won't be accepted, which can save time and frustration.

There are obviously lots of different approaches to your question, so it's really a matter of visual preference and/or style, but definitely consider doing 'in-line' validation as described above.

Comment: There will be one issue with the textFieldDidEndEditing method, what if the user never click the field?

Comment: You could in theory iterate through all the fields in each `didEndEditing` pass, if you wanted. Or you could simply not allow the user to use the submit button until all mandatory content has been entered.